# Is it possible to use Python threading to save multiple streams of audio by using one function?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have written a function that saves online radio, to listen that as a podcast. 
The saving function:

```
def save_radiostream():
   url=urllib.request.urlopen("http://myurl")
   timeout_start = time.time()
   filename="radiofiles/radio.mp3"
   f=open(filename, 'wb')
   timeout = 60*30   # [seconds]
   while time.time() < timeout_start + timeout:
      f.write(url.read(1024))
```

If I am going to call the function as a thread

```
_thread.start_new_thread( save_radiostream )
```

How to choose the time delay inside the while of the function to not interapt the audio? Or it will not work like that?

Comment: what you mean by _to not interapt the audio_?

Comment: @Arman to not have interference because of delay